# How to add Gaussian noise to light wave

Tags: noise

I want to find a method that can add independent Gaussian noise to different incoming light waves; Or find a noise light source that can emit light with Gaussian noise.It would be great if there were a source for the paper.Thank you so much.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Comment: "Incoming" to what? A lens, a fiber, a photodetector, or what? And how much noise do you want to add (measured in watts)? And what wavelength band do you want to cover?